# Join to another entity using String, not Object

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

**Question**

Is it possible to join an entity to another one using a String, not an Object?

I want join both entities to create a constraint. Indeed, a article could be create only if the author exists on the database.

**Exemple**

*Code using Object*

```
@Entity
public Article {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @ManyToOne
    private Author author;
    ...
}

@Entity
public Author {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String authorname;
    ...
}
```

*Code using String (my wish)*

```
@Entity
public Article {

    @Id
    private String id;
    @ManyToOne
    private String authorname;
    ...
}

@Entity
public Author {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private String authorname;
    ...
}
```

Something like:

```
@ManyToOne
@Join(table="author", name="authorname")
private String authorname;
```

Thanks for your answer.

**EDIT 1**

My objective is to only have the `authorname`, no other informations about the `author`.

So maybe is it possible to use `private Author author` and keep only his name?

To have something like:

```
{
    "title" : "Article title",
    "author" : "Author name",
    "date" : "2019-02-23",
    ...
}
```

and not :

```
{
    "title" : "Article title",
    "author" : {
         "authorname" : "Author name",
         "Age" : "51",
         ... 
    }
    "date" : "2019-02-23",
    ...
}
```

Comment: Nope, you cannot have a relation to a String. This is an "object oriented" language and the persistence process follows that. Any JPA docs would tell you that

Comment: Yep I asked this question because I don't found informations on JPA docs. Then exist it a way with JPA to check automatically that the authorname exists in the database (to avoid a manual check)?

Comment: What does this page say about "You cannot have a N-1 relation to a long or int field ?" http://www.datanucleus.org:15080/products/accessplatform_5_2/jpa/mapping.html#many_one_relations   If you have a String then YOU are deciding not to use a real relation, and YOU have to write a QUERY to check such things ... but then your design is crap at that point

Comment: So I have to check manually if user exists when an article is created or use `Author author` as attribute. I'm just trying things...

Comment: I edited my question to explain with examples my wish :).

Comment: Foreign key constraints are not checked by JPA. They're checked by the database, and are defined in the database. Use SQL to define them.

Comment: No. Associations are between entities. A String is not an entity. Just drop the ManyToOne. You just want to store a String in a column. Its a basic property. And JPA will update the column if you update the property, like for any other property.

Comment: Ok thanks. So I defined my constraint (with update cascade) into my SQL script. I didn't know JPA didn't handle foreign keys.

Comment: JPA does allow SPECIFICATION of FKs. It just does not check them and throw exceptions ... that is the databases job